# NewActivity not resolving in base class - should/how do I get the base class to recognize it?

Tags: eclipse, android-intent, android-activity, android-manifest

Using Eclipse on OSX:

I'm trying to start my first new activity from an Intent. The error seems to be here:

```
Intent newButton = new Intent(v.getContext(),RandomActivity.class);
startActivity(RandomActivity);
```

RandomActivity isn't getting resolved. I think I have it correct in my Manifest file. I think my imports are correct. Do I need to declare it somewhere in my base Activity? That doesn't seem to work. It's like the code doesn't recognize the existence of the new class, but I can't see where to fix that.

The rest of my code:

```
package course.examples.UI.Button;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import course.examples.UI.Button.R;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import course.examples.UI.Button.RandomActivity;

public class ButtonActivity extends Activity {
    int count = 0; 
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                Intent newButton = new Intent(v.getContext(),RandomActivity.class);
                startActivity(RandomActivity);
```

^Multiple markers at this line

- brandNewButton cannot be resolved to a type
- RandomActivity cannot be resolved to a variable

Note: brandNewButton WAS a class, but I deleted it, then went File->New->Class to create RandomActivity.java.

```
            }
    });
    }
}
```

My XML code is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:text="Press Me!" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        >
        </Button>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here's my Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="course.examples.UI.Button"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".ButtonActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".RandomActivity">
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Thanks in advance everyone, it's great to have such a community of support here for us noobies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need to do :

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                Intent newButton = new Intent(v.getContext(),RandomActivity.class);
```

**Here's the issue:** You are trying to start activity with different intent name ??

```
                "startActivity(RandomActivity);" // Wrong intent name
```

Check your intent!

**Instead**, just try using this :

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent newButton = new Intent(ButtonActivity.this, RandomActivity.class);

                startActivity(newButtom);//This is right
```

**Also**.. if your RandomActivity is not from your same package, register it with full path like:

```
<activity android:name="your packagename where random activity is.RandomActivity" />
```

Hope this helps.